# Can a single player world be opened to people that aren't on my network?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition-server

is there a way to make my single player world open to others? I know that there's LAN, but I'm talking about other people from farther away. For example, if I'm playing in Chicago and I want someone in Nebraska to be able to play my single player world, is there a way that I can make that work?

Comment: Check out Hamachi.

Comment: You can convert simpleplayer map to multiplayer map. Then you just have to host a server.

Answer (score 0):

You can not host a server to people outside of your network from your network, at that point you will have to use the Minecraft_Server(.exe or .jar) to host a server.  You can have your friends join either via Hamachi, port-forwarding, or an other VirualPublicNetwork.